# Existing file is not replaced using ProcessStartInfo.FileName = "xcopy"

Tags: c#, xcopy, processstartinfo

I have used the following code to copy the folder from one path to another path. If the copying  file is already exists it `does not replace the existing file`. Is there any command available with this like `xcopy/replace`?

```
private static void ProcessXcopy(string SolutionDirectory, string TargetDirectory)

        {

            // Use ProcessStartInfo class

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            //Give the name as Xcopy

            startInfo.FileName = "xcopy";

            //make the window Hidden

            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            //Send the Source and destination as Arguments to the process

            startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + SolutionDirectory + "\"" + " " + "\"" + TargetDirectory + "\"" + @" /e /y /I";

            try

            {

                // Start the process with the info we specified.

                // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.

                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))

                {

                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();

                }

            }

            catch (Exception exp)

            {

                throw exp;

            }



        }
```

**Referrence:** http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jawedmd/xcopy-using-C-Sharp-to-copy-filesfolders/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xcopy`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240268) should overwrite files by default (and the `/Y` flag suppresses prompts for confirmation). Could it be that the destination file is read-only? In that case, you also need to specify the `/R` flag.

Comment: startInfo.FileName = "xcopy"; in this how can i specify this, startInfo.FileName = "xcopy /R"; ????

Comment: @Ponmalar: No, it needs to go in the arguments. Replace the `@" /e /y /I"` string (at the end of your `startInfo.Arguments` line) with `@" /e /r /y /I"`.

Answer (score 1):

The note at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240268 describes /R as an additional parameter to overwrite read-only files. Have you tried adding that?

Comment: startInfo.FileName = "xcopy"; in this how can i specify this, startInfo.FileName = "xcopy /R"; ????